# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ratio' when using SMOTE

Tags: oversampling, imblearn, smote

I am using SMOTE to oversample as my dataset is imbalanced. I am getting an unexpected argument error. But in the documentation, the `ratio` argument is defined for SMOTE. Can someone help me understand where I am going wrong?

Code snippet

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
sm = SMOTE(random_state=42, ratio=0.6)
```

Error

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ratio'
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try replacing the 'Ratio' with 'sampling_strategy' :

```
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

sm = SMOTE(random_state=42, sampling_strategy=0.6)
```